# CakePHP setSource works only for once

Tags: php, cakephp

In my controller, i have those functions:

```
public function index ($id=null)
{
    if($id)
    {
        $this -> Word ->setSource($id);
    }
    $this -> set ('words', $this -> Word -> find('all'));
}

public function add()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $this->Word->create();
        if($this->Word->save($this->request->data))
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash("K");
            return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

Index takes (as parameter) name of table, and display the table. As you see, I told model to use this table by "setSource". But add function doesn't save new rows to $id table but to default "words".

Comment: What is `setSource()` and where do you see that as an option in CakePHP?

Comment: `setSource` is used in the controller to select a custom table for the model.

Answer (score 1):

Working as intended - you aren't setting the source in your `add` method, so Cake uses the default `Word` by convention. You need to find a way to pass that `$id` to your `add` method - via the URL or a hidden form field, perhaps.

for example...

```
public function add() {

    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        if(!empty($this->request->data['Word']['set_source'])) {
            $this->Word->setSource($this->request->data['Word']['set_source']);
        }
        $this->Word->create();
        if($this->Word->save($this->request->data)) {          
            $this->Session->setFlash("K");
            return $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

But be careful with this. Also `$id` is not a good variable name for this.